# What is the effect of destructive git operations on github forks?

Tags: git, github

I have a project hosted on github that is getting a little bloated:

https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/PropertyCross/

The repo is now around 160 MBytes. I would like to do a bit of clean-up, moving some of the files into a separate repo so that the 'cost' of cloning the main repo is smaller. I have researched how to do this, and I am happy that git allows me to remove folders from the repository indexes, reducing the overall size. I am also aware that this is a destructive operation.

My question is, if I perform this operation, and force push to github, what is the impact on the people who have forked the project? If they make changes to their fork and make pull requests will I still be able to merge them in? (I don't mind doing this manually).

Or, does it cause their forks to be useless?

Comment: Force pushing will not reduce the size of your repo. See github's help on permanently deleting files/commits for more info. Whatever you do will not affect forks at all, only mean there is no common history (will make it slightly harder to submit patches).

Comment: By submit patches, do you mean pull requests? Thanks for the info about github's delete help. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1):

your repository is actually 70 MB (as you self say in https://github.com/tastejs/PropertyCross/issues/189 ). This is the packed size of the git repository and does not include the size of your working directory.

It is this size that gets cloned. Your repository was about 70 MB in size even with your website/-directory. All code that you removed in commit 1faf01c04cb46df893592268407c3d84c403592f is still in the repository and is possible to get back. Every clone still downloads this.

To reduce your git-repo size you can run `git gc`. It will clean up a few things for you. To really remove stuff from your repo, (like ripping out the website-directory all together) you will need to use something like `git filter-branch`. You can a good tutorial about it here https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Maintaining+a+Git+Repository

There's a few other tricks to try to recompute your storage (`git repack`, `git gc --aggressive` etc.). I tried those on your repository and could not make it below 70 MB in size. Actually I got a worse size (72 MB). I guess that your repository already is pretty good packed.